# JustGage how to refresh it with jQuery.Ajax and MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

My JustGage code:

```
var g1;

    setInterval(function() {
              g1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }, 2500);

    var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: "cpu-usage", 
        value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: "CPU",
        label: "Usage",
        levelColorsGradient: false
     });
```

but I would like to use jQuery.Ajax with MVC and call a controller and return some value back and refresh JustGage. How can I use ajax call with JustGage?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/GetData",
   type: "POST",
   data: { data: newValze },
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {  
       alert(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I think it is simple. Just refresh it on Ajax success callback.
 $.ajax({
  url: "/Home/GetData",
  type: "POST",
  data: { data: newValze },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {  
   g1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
  }
});

Note: Please initialize JustGage before this call.
```

Comment: HI, thank you but I need to get back value from ActionResult in controler and set it in JustGage

Comment: In that case you will have to wait for server response and initialize Just Gage after you receive response from server. In short you will have initialize Just-Gage on Success and then refresh(both in success or complete callback).

Comment: and yes you can handle global variable so after initializing JustGage in success callback you can use it globally.